# Making build --inplace without providing to python setup.py build_ext

Tags: python, django, installation, cython

I have a python project in which I have to execute this command every now and then.

```
python setup.py build_clib
```

followed by

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I want this to happen with just a single line code of `python setup.py build` but that is not possible because I want my `.so` file `inplace`.

Is there any possible way of doing this?

Comment: Python official documentation https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/configfile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add these lines to your `setup.cfg` file.

```
[build_ext]
inplace=1
```